# Check if relationship of relationship if empty laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, laravel

I got a table `encuesta` that has a relationship `encuesta_pregunta`, the table `encuesta_pregunta` has a relationship to `encuesta_respuesta`, it return this

```
  "id": 4,
  //...table info...
  "encuesta_preguntas": [
    {
      "id": 10,
      "encuesta_id": 4,
      "pregunta_id": 5,
      //...table info....
      "encuesta_respuestas": [
        //this relationship can be empty
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 11,
      "encuesta_id": 4,
      "pregunta_id": 3,
      //...table info....
      "encuesta_respuestas": [

      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 12,
      "encuesta_id": 4,
      "pregunta_id": 2,
      //...table info....
      "encuesta_respuestas": [

      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

is there a way to checheck from without looping throught each `encuesta_preguntas` to know if `encuesta_respuesta` is empty?

o get the response above like this

```
$encuesta = Encuesta::with(['encuestaPreguntas' => function($preguntas) {
            $preguntas->with(['encuestaRespuestas' => function($respuestas) {
                $respuestas->where('user_id','=',auth()->id());
            }]);
        }])->where('fecha_inicio','<=',date('Y-m-d'))
        ->where('fecha_fin','>',date('Y-m-d'))
        ->first();
```

Comment: Can you show the relationship methods from your models?

Comment: Do you only want to include the `Encuesta` if the `encuesta_respuesta` is not empty? Or do you only want to include the `encuesta_pregunta` if the `encusta_respuesta` is not empty? So I suppose my real question is, what would you do if you knew that `encuesta_respuestas` was empty?

Answer (score 0):

**First.** You can do it with Laravel accesors

```
public function getHasEncuestasAttribute()
{
    return $this->encuesta_pregunta != [];
}
```

When you do `$model->has_encuestas` it will become true if the relationship isn't empty.

**Second.** Using relationship method `has` or `doesntHave`. If you want to get all the `encuesta` that have empty relationship you can call `Encuesta::doesntHave('encuesta_pregunta')` or the opposite that dont have empty relationship `Encuesta::has('encuesta_pregunta')`.